# lexical errors, does the case Two sequential Symbols count as a lexical error?

Tags: pascal, lexical

I looked over the internet for the lexical errors for Pascal programming language and there still this case which I don't know whether it's lexical error or semantic.

does the case two symbols (operators) after each other count as a lexical error or as a semantic error ?

example: `"+-", "<>", ";;"` or something like that.

thanks in advance.

Comment: That depends on the language. For example, `bash` uses `;;` as a case terminator, but in C or C++, for example, `;;` is two separate single-character semicolon tokens, which is neither a lexical error nor a semantic error, but might generate a warning for a useless empty statement between them...

Comment: @DigitalTrauma sorry, I was talking about Pascal, I though it would be the same for any programming language..

Comment: @twalberg what about in pascal ? it isn't a lexical error ?

Comment: It doesn't matter what kind of error it is. It's still an error and you need to fix it. What practical programming problem are you having where you need to distinguish between lexical and semantic errors?

Comment: @RaymondChen yes I do need to distinguish, I have an assignment to write in language c a program that lexical analyze an input..

Comment: @MoheTheDreamy It's been over 20 years since I last worked with Pascal, and I don't remember enough of the syntax to recall how Pascal would see a double ';'. But regardless of the language, a lexical error is one found during the splitting of the input into tokens, a syntactical error is something wrong with a sequence of tokens (e.g. forgetting a closing parenthesis on a function call), and semantic errors are even higher level - things like you can't insert objects into the middle of a stack, and so on...

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's a lexical error or a semantic error because you're going to detect it one way or the other. It's up to you how you want to detect it. You can try to detect it in the lexer if you want, or you can leave it to another pass. By the way, "+-" and ";;" are legal in C and Pascal, so they're not errors at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say it is part of the parsing process, semantic check comes only after that. (if you assume the basic sequence lexing,parsing,semantic check).

Btw, <> is a valid operation oin Pascal. (not equal).

Comment: Actually, all three are valid in Pascal.

Comment: Yes, but I meant to say that "<>" is an token (he calls it operator) in itself, not a combination. The lexer typically produces it as ONE token, similar as for e.g. ":="